# Getting error "Not Found" when the script is trying to find .sh in Dockerfile

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, odm

DockerFile - Path is rootDirectory/odm-ondocker/decisionserver/decisionserverconsole.

```
ARG FROMLIBERTY
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS builder
ARG ODMDOCKERDIR
ENV ODMDOCKERDIR $ODMDOCKERDIR
ENV SCRIPT /script
ENV APPS /config/apps
COPY $ODMDOCKERDIR/welcomepage /welcomepage
COPY $ODMDOCKERDIR/common/script $SCRIPT
COPY $ODMDOCKERDIR/common/drivers /config/resources
COPY $ODMDOCKERDIR/common/features $SCRIPT
COPY $ODMDOCKERDIR/decisionserver/decisionserverconsole/script $SCRIPT
COPY $ODMDOCKERDIR/decisionserver/decisionserverruntime/script $SCRIPT
# Use production liberty if needed
RUN echo $SCRIPT
COPY $ODMDOCKERDIR/resources/* /wlp-embeddable/
RUN chmod a+x $SCRIPT/fixWLPForProduction.sh && sync && $SCRIPT/fixWLPForProduction.sh
# Install missing require package in the alpine builder image
RUN apk add --no-cache bash perl ca-certificates wget
# Build Welcome page
RUN cd /welcomepage; mvn -B clean install | grep -v 'Download.*' && mkdir -p $APPS
```

I am getting error on line RUN chmod a+x $SCRIPT/fixWLPForProduction.sh && sync && $SCRIPT/fixWLPForProduction.sh as below:-

/bin/sh: /script/fixWLPForProduction.sh: not found
ERROR: Service 'odm-decisionserverconsole' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c chmod a+x $SCRIPT/fixWLPForProduction.sh && sync && $SCRIPT/fixWLPForProduction.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127

I am new to docker so not able to figure out why it's coming although the file is present inside root directory/common/scripts folder. I figured out, it's trying to find script folder which is under /odm-ondocker/common/script. I tried giving value of SCRIPT variable as /common/script but still it's giving as Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

RUN chmod a+x $SCRIPT/fixWLPForProduction.sh && sync && $SCRIPT/fixWLPForProduction.sh
 is looking for the script /script/fixWLPForProduction.sh as defined by your ENV SCRIPT command. But you said in your comment the script is /common/script/fixWLPForProduction.sh Trying using this instead 
ENV SCRIPT /common/script Or use the absolute path for the script. From there, you can know how to properly set your ENV variable

Comment: I reformatted it. Let me know if you need any more clarification.